# How to convert MS excel column into mysql column the easiest way?

Tags: mysql

I have different names in an excel column as

[image]

I want to convert these names to mysql columns as a b c d e f g h all having data type VARCHAR 255.

Please note that this is not adding excel column / list values to mysql column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make use of the same spreadsheet intuitively to create the SQL query for you.

First we create the table header and a formula to create column code

[image]

then fill series for all cells

[image]

copy the values and now you have your full SQL query

[image]